# How to process razorpay refund in php

Tags: php, razorpay

the official doc says by using curl the refund process will takesplace. How to implement this in php?

```
curl https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/pay_6ydSup2U7aFMsA/refund \
   -u {KEY}:{SECRET} \
   -d 'amount=15000' \
   -d 'reverse_all=1'
```

output:

```
{
  "id": "rfnd_6ye1vPrRFo6TdA",
  "entity": "refund",
  "amount": 15000,
  "currency": "INR",
  "payment_id": "pay_6ydSup2U7aFMsA",
  "notes": {},
  "created_at": 1482998305
}
```

I tries something like this:-

```
<?php
$url="https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/pay_jhjhdfsjfhsdjf/refund";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'user: rzp_test_key',
  'pass: rzp_test_pass'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($output);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

but nothing happens

Comment: Check what response you have got, or in case of some error code, check in API docs and error messages, Normally any third party provider are mentioned it,

Answer (score 3):

I do not recommend interacting with a Saas API using curl, it is better to use a PHP library for that, [razorpay has one](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-php).
Then refunding is this simple:

```php
$refund = $api->refund->create(array('payment_id' => $id)); // Creates refund for a payment
$refund = $api->refund->create(array('payment_id' => $id, 'amount'=>$refundAmount)); // Creates partial refund for a payment
$refund = $api->refund->fetch($refundId); // Returns a particular refund
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code and try i think it is because of ssl

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

$payment_id= Ord1123;

```
            $url            = 'https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/'.$payment_id.'/refund';
            $key_id         = "rzp_test_ad23x4IwXk7Z";
            $key_secret     = "cPPv2osad23dX9aKgwQAKy";
            $refundamt= 10*100;

            $fields_string  = "amount=$refundamt";
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $key_id.':'.$key_secret);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);
            echo $response;
```